# How can I see the whole message from a server Java to a C++ client?

Tags: java, c++, sockets, client-server

I need to send a string from a java server to a c++ client but the client receive the message divided into blocks or sometimes only some parts of the message, How can I see the whole message?
I don't need to send and receive because I receive the message but it is dived into blocks and it arrive some parts in different time but I need that these blocks are together and not separated.

This is my code:

**C++ client** :

```
    while(1){
        if( send(sock , nCartella,(unsigned)strlen(nCartella), 0) < 0){
            cout <<"Invio fallito"<<endl;
            return 1;
        }
        cout << "Messaggio inviato"<<endl;  

        if (recv(sock, buff, sizeof(buff)-1, 0) < 0)
        {
            cout << "Error receiving message " << endl;
            return 1;
        }
        message.append(buff);           
        break;                      
    }

    int finale=strcspn(buff,"\n");

    for(int a=0;a<finale;a++){
        cout<<buff[a];
    }

    cout << endl;
```

**Java server**:

```
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
                os.writeBytes(num_cartella+"\n");
```

What is wrong?Please hemp me to resolve this problem

Comment: what is the purpose of `while(1) { /*...*/ break;}` ?

Comment: This is a duplicate of the same question you asked two hours ago!

Comment: @SergeyA no no it's different. Before I need to send and receive the string but now, I receive and send the data but the string doesn't arrive to the client at the same time and I don't know how to take the whole message sent by the server

Comment: @SilviaBerardo, what's the difference?

Comment: @SergeyA read the prevoius comment, I edit it with the correct request

Comment: you might think, that it is two different questions, but actually it is about the same problem. As others try to explain, what you send via tcp is neither java nor C++ objects, but just bits and bytes. Thus, always when you use TCP, you have to define your protocol. For example: first 8bytes (or any other size you choose) is the length of the message and then comes Xbytes of the actual message. The sender has to implement this protocol as well as the reciever.

Answer (score 3):

1. Precisely define what you mean by a message. (Perhaps it's "up to 1,023 printable characters that do not contain a newline followed by a newline". Or whatever makes sense for your application.)
2. Write a function that receives a message, as you've defined it above.
3. Make sure that your "send" function sends messages, as you've defined it above.

The `recv` function just receives a bunch of bytes. It has no idea what your protocol considers to be a message or how to receive one. When you use TCP and you need application-level messages, you have to actually write code to send and receive application-level messages. You didn't do that.

When you use TCP to implement some application-level protocol, you have to actually define and implement that protocol. Since you need to send and receive messages, and TCP isn't a message protocol, you need to implement a message protocol on top of TCP. That means you have to both choose what the protocol will be and write send and receive functions that implement that choice.

Also, I notice that you ignore the return value of `recv`. So your code has no idea how many bytes it received. How can `append` possibly know how many bytes to append?

Similarly, you call `strcspn` on the buffer. But `strcspn` is only for C-style strings. If you want to return the message as a C-style string, again, you have to write code to do that. The `recv` function just returns chunks of raw bytes, not C-style strings.

Comment: She already asked the same question two hours ago. I am unsure why she does this.

Comment: append is not important because I don't use it, I need to delete it but, when I receive the message from the server it id divided into different blocks and it doesn't whole.. How can I receive the whole message? I don't find any function to use

Comment: @SilviaBerardo You have to write the function. Read my answer.